# Code Folding in ELPY Not Working

Tags: elpy, code-folding

I used several IDEs for Python.  I like Spyder, but I have have been a pretty obsessive Emacs user for a LONG time.  I install ELPY.  It works very well for my needs.  However, I cannot get code folding to work.  Whenever I click on anything and then choose **EPLY->Code folding->Hide/show at point** (through the menu system), I get the following error:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable hs-minor-mode)
> elpy-folding-toggle-at-point()
> funcall-interactively(elpy-folding-toggle-at-point)
> call-interactively(elpy-folding-toggle-at-point nil nil)
> command-execute(elpy-folding-toggle-at-point)

Does anybody know how to get this working?  It does not matter much where I click on a function or pretty much anything.

Comment: Hide/Show minor mode works very well inside ELPY.  However, I still find it very strange the ELPY's menus for code folding/unfolding with the error changing to:

  `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function hs-life-goes-on)
   hs-life-goes-on(nil)
   elpy-folding-toggle-at-point()
   funcall-interactively(elpy-folding-toggle-at-point)
   call-interactively(elpy-folding-toggle-at-point nil nil)
   command-execute(elpy-folding-toggle-at-point)`

Any ideas?

Comment: ```(void-variable hs-minor-mode) ```means the the variable hs-minor-mode is ```nil```,   and becomes true if you enable the mode with ```M-x hs-minor-mode```. After this is enabled, you may type the command ```ELPY -> Code-folding ->...```. Try if this works for you, you may add a hook to elpy config to enable this mode automatically. Also see the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244485/python-code-folding-in-emacs.

Comment: @Ian, unfortunately, your suggestion is the first thing I tried.  I did `M-x hs-minor-mode` and did confirm that the var `hs-minor-mode` evaluates to `t` using `M-: hs-minor-mode`.  I added `hs-minor-mode` as a hook for `elpy-mode`.  As I mentioned, I can fold/unfold code using `hs-minor-mode`, but the ELPY menus throw an error.

Comment: Allow me to expand on the issues. Once you have enabled `hs-minor-mode`, the ELPY menus do fold/unfold code.  However, they fold and unfold code as well as throwing the error I mentioned.  What does not make sense is that the symbol `hs-life-goes-on` is defined (contrary to the error at the top of the stack trace) as if defined as a macro.

Comment: Folding appears to be in development and not yet released: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/commit/0c7207ba124e4dca1856a9d86f11e4401dc36775.

Comment: As of ELPY's latest version, code folding works perfectly.  I am on Emacs 26.2 and ELPY  version 20200112.1819 (as specified by package on Emacs).